# Selecting a field in every object of a javascript array

Tags: javascript, loops, indexing

I have an authentication scheme that allows a user to be an employee of multiple companies. So when they are authenticated with an `access_token`, that `access_token` allows them to carry out a transaction on any one of the companies they are an employee at. So basically the user has one login and they can interact with all of their companies without logging out.

Whenever they try to carry out an action, I need to make sure they are an employee of the company they are trying to change.

The authorize function has an `employees` object in its callback. This is a list like this:

```
[ { _id: 555c990c37b3af9214754416,
    company: 555c97d6b0b7e88d140810c6,
    user: 555c990c37b3af9214754415,
    __v: 0,
    date_added: Wed May 20 2015 10:23:07 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    permissions: { write: true, read: true } },
  { _id: 555c994937b3af921475441b,
    company: 555c992537b3af9214754417,
    user: 555c990c37b3af9214754415,
    __v: 0,
    date_added: Wed May 20 2015 10:23:07 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    permissions: { write: true, read: true } } ]
```

This will be done every time a call is made to the API, that is, a list of the user's `employee` objects will be examined; so I want to select the company field from each object in the fastest and simplest way possible. While this can easily be accomplished using a for loop and compiling a list of `company`, I need it to be much cleaner.

*Is there a one liner for this type of thing, a way to select a field at each index without looping, or looping done behind the scenes?*

Comment: Could you use [lodash’s `_.pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck)?

Comment: @minitech, that seems like it would work, but it is returning an object instead of an array, any thoughts there?

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: ```var companies = lodash.pluck(employees, 'company');
console.log(companies);
console.log(typeof(companies));``` Employees is an object, so that could be the problem.

Comment: @minitech, if you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lodash and similar libraries provide [`pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck), which should do what you want:

```
var companies = _.pluck(employees, 'company');
```

Comment: `_.pluck` actually calls `_.map` you should get the same result from `_.map(employees, 'company')` with a little less overhead.

Comment: @chrisvdp: Sure; I just find the name a little more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a `bool` for if the employee is in the company. The nice things about this approach is that it short circuits out of the loop when a true is found.

```
var isInCompany = _.some(employees, function(employee){
    employee.company === companyId;
});
```

Depending on the browsers you support (IE9+), you can use the native object as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: This is nice to know, however it doesn't fit in my application as smoothly as the others right now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Array.map function like:

```
yourList.map(function(obj){return obj.company})
```

this will return a list of all the companies.